# "lein help" outputs a lot "_Problem loading_"

Tags: clojure, leiningen

install leiningen by download the script and follow the github instruction.  On a Ubuntu/Linux box, I got a lots "Problem loading", and very few google results about the problem, here is the output:

```
$lein help
Leiningen is a tool for working with Clojure projects.

Several tasks are available:
leiningen.classpath  Problem loading:
clean       Remove compiled class files and jars from project.
leiningen.compile  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.deps__init
leiningen.deploy  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.compile__init
leiningen.deps  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.deps__init
help        Display a list of tasks or help for a given task.
leiningen.install  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.jar__init
leiningen.interactive  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.compile__init
leiningen.jar  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.jar__init
leiningen.javac  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.classpath__init
new         Create a new project skeleton.
leiningen.plugin  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.jar__init
leiningen.pom  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.util.maven__init
leiningen.repl  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.compile__init
leiningen.retest  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.test__init
leiningen.run  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.compile__init
search      Search remote maven repositories for matching jars.
leiningen.test  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.test__init
leiningen.test!  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.deps__init
leiningen.trampoline  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.compile__init
leiningen.uberjar  Problem loading: Could not initialize class leiningen.uberjar__init
upgrade     Upgrade Leiningen to the latest stable release.
version     Print version for Leiningen and the current JVM.

Run lein help $TASK for details.
See also: readme, tutorial, copying, sample, deploying and news.
```

Comment: Which version of leiningen are you using?

Comment: Leiningen 1.7.1-SNAPSHOT on Java 1.6.0_22 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ususal steps for 'fixing' lein problems:

- run `lein upgrade` (this may not help here)
- move `~/.m2` to `~/.m2.bak`
- run `lein self-install` again
- download the latest copy

Comment: Tweaking ~/.m2 shouldn't be necessary for problems involving Leiningen itself, just for problems involving dependencies fetched with Leiningen.